# How to create a blockchain for record keeping

Tags: blockchain

I have read a lot about how blockchain could be implemented for other technologies other than crypto currencies. I did some research on how to create a fork (build your own) blockchain but they were for creating your own alternative currencies.  I was wondering if this community would know or could point me in the right direction as to creating a blockchain that would be used for record keeping.

I have a background in development coding and I have studied solidity in parallel with the ethereum blockchain.  I have forked the go-ethereum source code and built it out on an ubuntu virtual machine.  However, I am finding it hard to find discussions on creating blockchains for record purposes.  I have found online articles on the concept of using blockchain technology for record keeping but finding a hard time on how to kick start this project.  Would I have to build a blockchain and use code to build a user interface to interact with it and instead of sending transactions to the block chain, find other data input to send to the blockchain?

Comment: came here to find answers for this today, glad that you already started

Comment: Not directly related to this question, but may help someone exploring on blockchain. https://www.bigchaindb.com/whitepaper/bigchaindb-whitepaper.pdf

Comment: Thank you Saravanan,  Let us see what the good community has to say.

Comment: Saravanan, Thank you for that whitepaper.  I did read the bitcoin whitepaper but did not find this one.  Thank you for this, So far it makes for a great read with the architecture and code used to pass transactions/data to and from it.  I am still reading further if there are details of actually building the DB, i.e. server specs, preferred database used i.e. they say mysql and nosql but how are they configured in reference to tables, etc. and how replication of DB and creation of nodes go.  Let me see what else it says, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Blockchain for record keeping, you can:

1. **Use a Blockchain that exists**. In this case, for example, I think that it would be a good chance to use Ethereum. [Here](https://www.ethereum.org/token), you have a tutorial about it. Nowadays, there are many people who use the Ethereum network for record keeping, although you should pay some Ethers. [Provenance](https://www.provenance.org/) is an example and an interesting project about it.
2. **Create your own Blockchain**. For that, if I were you I would use the [Hyperledger Fabric](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Fabric gives you the chance to create a private Blockchain, so you could control the acces. There, you can deploy the Smart Contract that you require.

When you create a Blockchain or you use one that exists, you deploy your own Smart Contract. There, you define how is going to be your code. Then, you have to define a interfaz which will call to your Blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

I agree It's better to **create your own Blockchain**.
You can prefer to use [IBM Block Chain](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/blockchain/) solution to create your private blockchain. It will help you to handle and configure setting using dashboards as required.